# Exactly like Adobe example- but Keyboard is undefined property?

Tags: actionscript-3

Yes I wanted to know the reason for error message.

```
import flash.events.*;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);

function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode ==Keyboard.SPACE) 
    {
        removeChild(Start1);
        Start1 = null;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a question or just a rant? Anyway, the code you added to your question was missing a closing `}`.

Comment: @MartyWallace Surely it's a question. OP just didn't read manuals well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
```

Never forget importing something that's not in top level of Flash classes.

Comment: Why doesn't Adobe list that or anyone else? I tried to put something like in FD but it wouldn't give me any help.

Comment: Try harder, I have to say. I use FD too, and this works for me without any extra hassle. Note that this should be in the beginning (where your other imports are) of the file that uses `Keyboard`.